# ¿Se puede cambiar los atributos src, width y height de una imagen que ya antes le asigné atributos diferentes?

Tags: javascript

Intento setear nuevos valores a una imagen con **JS**, primero al crear el objeto sí se asignan pero al quererlos cambiar no se aplican, tengo duda en si es posible desde **JS** o tengo que usar **CSS**. 
El src de la img es obtenido del valor del atributo de un Objeto, el constructor de la clase es: (`id, name, position, level, imgFront, imgBack`)

```
var $img1  = document.getElementById('img1')
var $img2  = document.getElementById('img2')
//a las imagenes se les asignará el valor de un objeto y atributos de dimensión
//en el HTML no tienen mas que el "id"

function setImgAttributes($element, attributes) {
    for(let attribute in attributes)
        $element.setAttribute(attribute, attributes[attribute])
}

function imgTurno1() {
    setImgAttributes($img1, {
        src: `${person1.imgBack}`,
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
    })
    setImgAttributes($img2, {
        src: `${person2.imgFront}`,
        width: 120,
        height: 120,
    })
}

function imgTurno2() {
    setImgAttributes($img1, {
        src: `${person1.imgFront}`,
        width: 120,
        height: 120,
    })
    setImgAttributes($img2, {
        src: `${person2.imgBack}`,
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
    })
}

//después de instanciar los objetos se asignan los primeros valores sin problema
imgTurno1()

//durante el proceso al interactuar se intenta setear nuevos valores a la imagen pero no se aplican
imgTurno2()
```

Si lo intento por separado en la consola del navegador si me aplica los cambios pero me arroja esta alerta:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. at `<anonymous>`"

```
$img2 = setImgAttributes($img2, {
        src: `${person2.imgBack}`,
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
    })
```

En un principio si tenia declaradas las imagenes en js como const, pero despues de intentar esto en la consola las cambie a var. Esta es mi primer pregunta. Gracias desde ya!

Answer (score 0):

Comunidad, una disculpa realmente el fragmento de código que tengo esta correcto y se puede aplicar sin problemas.
El error lo tuve por estar buscando los resultados al probar el archivo equivocado en lugar del archivo local.(ya saben cosas de novatos)
No voy a borrar la pregunta por si en algún momento a alguien le sirve. A menos claro que algún moderador lo solicite.

```
function changePosition() {
    switch(turno) {
        case 1:
            imgTurno2()
            $img1.classList.toggle('rotar')
            $img2.classList.toggle('rotar') 
            turno++
            break
        case 2:
            imgTurno1()
            $img1.classList.toggle('rotar')
            $img2.classList.toggle('rotar')
            turno--
            break
    }
}
```

En esa parte de la aplicación se iteran las imagenes llamando a esta función con el evento click a un botón.

Comment: ¿Entonces cuál era el error?

Comment: Tenia abierto el HTML desde un servidor en la red en lugar de mi archivo local.

Comment: Considero entonces si es mejor eliminar tu pregunta ya que no es problema en si que a otros les pueda llegar a servir, sino mas bien un *descuido*

Comment: Si que fue un descuido de novato, si no te molesta voy a esperar otra más, para tampoco pasar por alto la edición de FRANCISCO J. BLANCO y pensando en que tal vez si alguien tiene esa pregunta pueda llegar a ese código